# Ｒでデータフレームから特定のデータフレームをフィルタリングする方法

Tags: r

形態素解析の結果であるデータフレームdata1（1523行4列）から、別のデータフレームdata2（150行4列）の値と一致する行を削除したいのですが、
どのような関数を用いたらいいのかがわかりません。

以下が試してみた結果になります。

**コード①**

```
data1[!(data1$Term == data2$Term),]
```

**結果①**

```
            Term  Info1  Info2 Freq
32        あつい 形容詞   自立    1
33    ありがたい 形容詞   自立    3
34          いい 形容詞   自立   39
……（略）
413       上がる   動詞   自立    6
414       上回る   動詞   自立    1
415       乗せる   動詞   自立    1
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 1273 rows ]
 警告メッセージ: 
 data1$Term == data2$Term で: 
   長いオブジェクトの長さが短いオブジェクトの長さの倍数になっていません
```

**コード②**

```
data1[!grepl(data2$Term, data1$Term),]
```

**結果①**

```
            Term  Info1  Info2 Freq
32        あつい 形容詞   自立    1
33    ありがたい 形容詞   自立    3
34          いい 形容詞   自立   39
……（略）
414       上回る   動詞   自立    1
415       乗せる   動詞   自立    1
416     拭き取る   動詞   自立    1
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 1272 rows ]
 警告メッセージ: 
 grepl(data2$Term, data1$Term) で: 
   引数 'pattern' は 1 を超える長さなので、最初の要素だけが使われます
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `%in%` ですかね。`data1[!(data1$Term %in% data2$Term),]`

Comment: `%in%`は完全に見落としていました…！ありがとうございます。試してみましたが、無事にフィルタリングすることができました！